# Why does relation[admin_level="2"] not select all countries?

Tags: overpass-api

I have expected the following Overpass query to return all relations with `admin_level="2"`, i. e. all countries.

```
relation[admin_level="2"];
out tags;
```

However, at least the relation for Finland is not returned, although such a relation with `admin_level="2"` *does* exist:

```
relation(54224);
out tags;
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue. According to the following query, rel 54224 is part of the result.

```
relation[admin_level="2"];
rel._(54224);
out tags;
```

You didn’t exactly write how you came to your conclusion for the first query. In case you were using overpass turbo, be aware that the browser search does NOT work there.

Download the query results to a file instead, and inspect the file locally. You will see that relation 54224 is included in the original query result.